# Input não envia valor do combobox

Tags: php, input, combobox

```
<TR>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="myinputstyle" size=16  >Cidade:</TD>
        <TD>
         <select name="cidades"  >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
                <option value="ca">Curitiba</option>
                <option value="fs">Florianopolis</option>
            </select>

            <INPUT type=text name="cidades" size="16" class="myinputstyle">

        </TD>

    <TD bgcolor="#EBEBEB" >

</TD>
```

Esse código envia a opção escolhida do combobox mas o valor não é gravado no banco de dados, se eu não utilizar o combobox o valor é enviado normalmente o problema só acontece quando uso o combobox aonde esta o erro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TR>    
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="myinputstyle"  >Cidade: </TD>
         <TD>
         <select name="cidade" id="cidades" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="scs">São Caetano do Sul</option>
                <option value="sa">Santo André</option>
                <option value="sbc">São Bernardo do Campo</option>
            </select>
        </TD>
```

Este código resolveu o problema e insere o valor no banco de dados no caso ele ira inserir o que estiver dentro do value exemplo, scs, sa ou sbc obrigado a todos que responderam

Answer (score 0):

Pelo código que você postou, me parece que você está definindo o `input` e o `select` com o mesmo nome. Faça assim por exemplo:

**formulario.html**

```
    <form action="teste.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <TR>
        <TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="myinputstyle" size=16  >Cidade:</TD>
                <TD>
                 <select name="cidades_select">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="ca">Curitiba</option>
                        <option value="fs">Florianopolis</option>
                    </select>

                    <INPUT type=text name="cidades_text" size="16" class="myinputstyle">

                </TD>

            <TD bgcolor="#EBEBEB" >

        </TD>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <input type="submit" value="Testar">
    </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

E pegue o valor selecionado assim:

**teste.php**

```
<?php
$cidade_select = $_POST['cidades_select'];
$cidade_digitado = $_POST['cidades_text'];
echo 'Cidade do Combobox: '.$cidade_select.'<br />';
echo 'Cidade do input text: '.$cidade_digitado;
```

Comment: Como passo esse codigo que vc coloco dentro do input ? pq o input que faz o envio para o bd

Comment: Mude o `name` dos inputs do HTML como está ai em cima. Eles nunca podem ser iguais. Depois altere o $_POST do PHP que atualmente você tem com os nomes que você definiu no HTML.

Comment: Fiz assim e não deu certo  <INPUT type=text name="cidades" size="16" class="myinputstyle" value="<?php $cidade_select = $_POST['cidades_text']; ?>">

Comment: O código que fiz foi para você enviar o que o usuário digitou e selecionou para o código PHP. Para você fazer desse jeito você tem que trocar o cidades_text por `cidades` mas lembrando que o name="" nunca pode ser igual em um formulário. No seu caso você tinha colocado o name `cidades` no <select> e <input> isso não pode acontecer

Comment: Mestre fiz assim agora tmb continua dando erro não sei o que fazer <INPUT type=text name="cidades" size="16" class="myinputstyle" value="<?php $cidade_select = $_POST['cidades_select']; echo $cidade_select ?>">

Comment: Editei o código... Faça daquele jeito... O formulário você salva em um arquivo chamado formulario.html e o código PHP voce salva como teste.php e faz o teste.

Comment: Mestre se eu baixar o team view vc conecta aqui ? não deu certo

Comment: add no facebook. fb.com/alisson.acioli